Calculate the mean and variance of a stochastic process?
I was introduced to the Polya Urn problem in statistics (a problem where we draw a ball from an urn and place another ball back of the same color). These are the formulas for the mean and variance of the Polya urn (w= initial number of white ball, b = initial number of black ball,N = total number of balls at start, n = turn, d=1):
$$ E(X_n) = \frac{w}{w+b} = \frac{w}{N} $$
$$ Var(X_n) = \frac{w b}{N^2(N+1)} \cdot \frac{n(N+d)}{N+nd} $$
I tried to simulate this in R (starting with 5:1 ratio):
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(gridExtra)

w <- 5    # white balls
b <- 1    # black balls
N <- w + b  # total balls
d <- 1    # number of balls put back at each turn
n_draws <- 10000

theoretical_values <- function(n) {
    mean_th <- w/N
    var_th <- (w*b)/(N^2*(N+1)) * (n*(N+d))/(N+n*d)
    return(c(mean_th, var_th))
}

run_polya_sim <- function() {
    urn <- c(rep("white", w), rep("black", b))
    draws <- numeric(n_draws)
    
    results <- data.frame(
        draw = 1:n_draws,
        emp_mean = NA,
        emp_var = NA,
        theo_mean = NA,
        theo_var = NA
    )
    
    for(i in 1:n_draws) {
        drawn <- sample(urn, 1)
        draws[i] <- ifelse(drawn == "white", 1, 0)
        urn <- c(urn, rep(drawn, d))
        
        results$emp_mean[i] <- mean(draws[1:i])
        results$emp_var[i] <- ifelse(i > 1, var(draws[1:i]), 0)
        
        theo <- theoretical_values(i)
        results$theo_mean[i] <- theo[1]
        results$theo_var[i] <- theo[2]
    }
    
    return(results)
}

set.seed(123)
results <- run_polya_sim()

p1 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = draw)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = emp_mean, color = "Empirical")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = theo_mean, color = "Theoretical")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Empirical" = "red", "Theoretical" = "blue")) +
    labs(title = "Mean Values",
         x = "Number of Draws",
         y = "Mean") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = draw)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = emp_var, color = "Empirical")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = theo_var, color = "Theoretical")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Empirical" = "red", "Theoretical" = "blue")) +
    labs(title = "Variance Values",
         x = "Number of Draws",
         y = "Variance") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)

But it seems like the results dont match (not in short term and not in long term)?

Am I doing this incorrectly? Is this how you simulate a stochastic process and take its mean and variance? Why is my simulation not matching the theoretical formulas?
Version 2 Code based on comments (I think these simulations look more realistic):
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(gridExtra)
library(dplyr)

w <- 5        # white balls
b <- 1        # black balls
N <- w + b    # total balls
d <- 1        # number of balls put back each turn
n_draws <- 1000  
n_sims <- 100  

theoretical_values <- function(n) {
    mean_th <- w/N
    var_th <- (w*b)/(N^2*(N+1)) * (n*(N+d))/(N+n*d)
    return(c(mean_th, var_th))
}

run_single_polya_sim <- function() {
    urn <- c(rep("white", w), rep("black", b))
    draws <- numeric(n_draws)
    
    for(i in 1:n_draws) {
        drawn <- sample(urn, 1)
        draws[i] <- ifelse(drawn == "white", 1, 0)
        urn <- c(urn, rep(drawn, d))
    }
    
    return(draws)
}

# multiple simulations
set.seed(123)
all_sims <- replicate(n_sims, run_single_polya_sim(), simplify = FALSE)

   
results <- data.frame(
    draw = 1:n_draws,
    emp_mean = NA,
    emp_var = NA,
    theo_mean = NA,
    theo_var = NA
)

# for each draw, calculate mean and variance across all simulations
for(i in 1:n_draws) {
    # Get the i-th draw from all simulations
    ith_draws <- sapply(all_sims, function(x) x[i])
    
    # mean and variance across simulations for this draw
    results$emp_mean[i] <- mean(ith_draws)
    results$emp_var[i] <- var(ith_draws)
    
    #  theoretical values
    theo <- theoretical_values(i)
    results$theo_mean[i] <- theo[1]
    results$theo_var[i] <- theo[2]
}

  
p1 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = draw)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = emp_mean, color = "Empirical")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = theo_mean, color = "Theoretical")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Empirical" = "red", "Theoretical" = "blue")) +
    labs(title = "Mean Values (Averaged across simulations)",
         x = "Number of Draws",
         y = "Mean") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(results, aes(x = draw)) +
    geom_line(aes(y = emp_var, color = "Empirical")) +
    geom_line(aes(y = theo_var, color = "Theoretical")) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("Empirical" = "red", "Theoretical" = "blue")) +
    labs(title = "Variance Values (Averaged across simulations)",
         x = "Number of Draws",
         y = "Variance") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(legend.title = element_blank())

# ci for mean
ci_data <- data.frame(
    draw = 1:n_draws,
    lower = results$emp_mean - 2 * sqrt(results$emp_var/n_sims),
    upper = results$emp_mean + 2 * sqrt(results$emp_var/n_sims)
)

p1 <- p1 + geom_ribbon(data = ci_data, 
                       aes(x = draw, ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                       alpha = 0.2, fill = "red")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)

I think this is correct now? The average of all simulations hover around the starting ratio as time increases, while the variance is constantly increasing with time.


You must be doing the simulation incorrectly.  After $1000$ draws, so with $1006$ balls, each ball must have an original ancestor which is one of the $6$ original balls, each equally likely, so the expected empirical mean should be $\frac56 \approx 0.833$.  Perhaps try it again with drawing $1$ or $2$ balls.

What is wrong is that you only run the simulation once.  If you had used set.seed(2024) so running it a second time, you would have got a much higher value.  But you need to run it many times.

You appear to be confusing the empirical mean of a realization $(x_1, \ldots, x_i)$ with the expectation of $X_i.$  In short, your simulation won't match the formulas because it's not computing what the formulas refer to.  Whether this is a conceptual matter or a coding error is difficult to determine, so it would help to have more than the code to go on: could you describe what you think the code is doing?

Thank you henry

Hey whuber, here is how I tried to set everything up (this for version 2 of the code):

part 1: The run_single_polya_sim function simulates one complete sequence of 1000 draws: it starts with an urn (5 white, 1 black ball), randomly draws a ball, records 1 for white or 0 for black, and adds another ball of the drawn color back to the urn. It returns the full sequence of 1000 draws.

part 2: via replicate, run this single simulation 100 times, creating 100 different sequences of 1000 draws each.

part 3: for each draw number (1 through 1000), look across all 100 simulations to calculate:
A ) The empirical mean (average proportion of white balls at that draw number across all simulations)
B )The empirical variance (variance of the proportion at that draw number across simulations)
C )The theoretical mean and variance using the theoretical formulas

The process is a series of random variables $(X_n).$ It is evident from your formulas and code that these random variables are the proportions of white balls in the urn when there are $n$ balls in the urn.  Consequently, the correct formulas for the moments are
$$E[X_n] = \frac{w}{w+b}$$
and, letting $d=1$ refer to the number of additional balls placed in the urn at each step,
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = E[X_n](1-E[X_n]) \left(\frac{d}{w+b+d} - \frac{w+b}{w+b+d}\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
To estimate these moments with a simulation, you have to

Simulate some independent realizations of this process that go out at least through step $n.$

As usual, use the mean and sample variance of these realizations of $X_n$ (for fixed $n$) to estimate $E[X_n]$ and $\operatorname{Var}(X_n),$ respectively.


In R it is convenient to do this with the replicate function.  It will place each realization into a column of the output matrix X.  Thus, the index $n$ of the process designates a single row of X, whence you can obtain row means via rowMeans and row variances using the apply function, as in
apply(X, 1, var)

Letting f be a function to generate one realization, here is reproducible code to start with $1$ black ball, $5$ white balls, and to simulate realizations of the next $n=49$ variables $X_6, X_7, \ldots, X_{55}.$ It creates 2e4 (ten thousand) independent realizations (taking a few seconds to do so).
set.seed(17)
n <- 49; b <- 1; w <- 5
X <- replicate(2e4, f(n, b, w))

For completeness, here is an implementation of f.
f <- function(n, b = 1, w = 1) {
  W <- c(w, rep(NA, n))          # White ball counts
  N <- seq_len(n) + b + w - 1    # Total counts
  for (i in seq_along(N)) {
    p <- W[i] / N[i]             # Chance to draw a white ball
    W[i+1] <- W[i] + sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(1-p, p))
  }
  W / c(N, n + b + w)            # Proportions of white balls
}

We can plot these row means and row variances as a function of $n$ and, for reference (shown in red) we can plot the functions given by the expressions for $E$ and $\operatorname{Var}$ above;

The agreement is good (notice the very small range of values in the left hand plot: you're looking at a random walk around the expectation of $w/(w+b) = 5/6 = 0.8333\ldots$).

The takeaway: The mean of the process (i.e. the ratio of colors) hovers around the starting ratio while the variance slowly grows to infinity? The mean of the process converges to a Beta Distribution ... but the variance of the process does not. Is this correct?

The variance reaches an asymptote (a finite limit), as you can see by examining the formula for it: as $n$ grows large, the factor of $1/n$ vanishes, leaving a constant.  I don't understand what you mean by a mean converging to a "distribution:" the mean is a sequence of numbers (indexed by $n$) that happens to be a constant sequence.

could you please show me how you derived the equation for the variance? or should I post another question?

You can look up that result or use techniques presented here at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/632967 or https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/433010.

I tried but got stuck https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/658243/finding-the-variance-of-a-stochastic-process
