Using statistical sampling and machine learning together?
I have data with labels $y_i \in \{0,1\}$ and some features $x_i$. Most $y$'s are 0 (e.g. 99% to 1%). I want to fit a random forest classification model on this data.
I was wondering if this approach is used in statistics to avoid problems with imbalances in the data (e.g. a combination of bagging and resampling):

Get all rows where $y_i = 1$ (let's call this set $B$)
Randomly sample from the $y_i = 0$ rows to get a set the same size as $B$ (call each sample $S_k$)
Train a model $f_k$ on $B \cup S_k$
Do this $K$ times to get models $f_1, f_2, ..., f_K$

Then for any new input $x_{new}$, our prediction is just the average:
$$ \text{prediction} = \frac{f_1(x_{new}) + f_2(x_{new}) + ... + f_K(x_{new})}{K} $$
Then : For any new observation $x_{new}$, if we have $K$ models, we can define the agreement score $A(x_{new})$ as:
$$ A(x_{new}) = \max\left(\frac{\sum_{k=1}^K I(f_k(x_{new}) = 0)}{K}, \frac{\sum_{k=1}^K I(f_k(x_{new}) = 1)}{K}\right) $$
This gives us a score between 0.5 (perfect disagreement) and 1.0 (perfect agreement). A threshold can be chosen that decides what level of Agreement should be accepted as a threshold (e.g. see if higher model agreement correlates to more accurate predictions)?

Welcome to Cross Validated! What are the problems you see with imbalance? You may be interested in the links in my profile.

Thank you Dave!!! I will see if I can find some relevant links in your profile

Did you have an opinion about thsi question?https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/657751/calculate-the-mean-and-variance-of-a-stochastic-process ... some people left comments but unfortunately no answer

In the sklearn implementation, there is the argument class_weight which does not do a balanced sampling as you propose but achieves the same effect by weighting a sample according to the frequency of its class. In your case, positive samples would have a much stronger influence than negative samples.
The class of a test sample is then just predicted as always, i.e., every tree casts a vote for a sample which it weighs by the estimated probability. The predicted class is then the one with the highest mean probability estimates across the trees.
