Finding the variance of a stochastic process
This is part 2 of this question Calculate the mean and variance of a stochastic process?
For the Polya Urn problem, I am trying to understand why the ratio of the variance is:
$$\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = E[X_n](1-E[X_n]) \left(\frac{d}{w+b+d} - \frac{w+b}{w+b+d}\frac{1}{n}\right).$$
I know that the general variance formula is $E[X_n^2] - (E[X_n])^2$ and that $E[X_n] = \frac{w}{w+b}$. I only need to find $E[X_n^2]$.
When we have $n$ balls, if we draw a white ball ( probability $X_{n-1}$), we add $d$ white balls. If we draw a black ball (probability $1-X_{n-1}$), we add $d$ black balls ($k$ is the number of white balls added in previous steps).
$$ X_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{w + (k+1)d}{w+b+nd} & \text{if white ball drawn} \\
\frac{w + kd}{w+b+nd} & \text{if black ball drawn}
\end{cases} $$
Using the law of total expectation for the second moment:
$$ E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}\left(\frac{w + (k+1)d}{w+b+nd}\right)^2 + (1-X_{n-1})\left(\frac{w + kd}{w+b+nd}\right)^2 $$
By expanding and substituting:
$$ \left(\frac{w + (k+1)d}{w+b+nd}\right)^2 = \frac{w^2 + 2w(k+1)d + ((k+1)d)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} $$
$$ \left(\frac{w + kd}{w+b+nd}\right)^2 = \frac{w^2 + 2wkd + (kd)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} $$
$$ E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}\frac{w^2 + 2w(k+1)d + ((k+1)d)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + (1-X_{n-1})\frac{w^2 + 2wkd + (kd)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} $$
I tried to expand again:
$$ \begin{align*}
E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] &= \frac{X_{n-1}(w^2 + 2w(k+1)d + ((k+1)d)^2)}{(w+b+nd)^2} + \frac{(1-X_{n-1})(w^2 + 2wkd + (kd)^2)}{(w+b+nd)^2} \\
&= \frac{w^2 + 2wkd + (kd)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + X_{n-1}\frac{2wd + 2d^2(k+1)}{(w+b+nd)^2}
\end{align*} $$
I know that I need to take the expectation one more time so that $E(E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}]) = E[X_n^2]$
But this is where I got stuck and don't know how to proceed. I feel like I am going in circles. Any ideas on how to continue?

In don't understand your definition of $X_n$ and why and how would you compute conditional expectations of $X_n$ conditional on $X_{n-1}$?

Im really lost Sextus ... I feel like giving up on this question and just accepting the simulation answer :(

You are writing $$X_n = \begin{cases}
\frac{w + (k+1)d}{w+b+nd} & \text{if white ball drawn} \
\frac{w + kd}{w+b+nd} & \text{if black ball drawn}
\end{cases}$$ what does this mean? Can you add an explanation independent from the other question that you refer to.

If we draw a white ball:
The numerator becomes $w + (k+1)d$ because we:

Start with $w$ initial white balls
Have added $k$ white balls in previous steps
Add one more set of $d$ white balls for this draw
The denominator $w+b+nd$ represents the total number of balls after $n$ draws


If we draw a black ball:
The numerator is $w + kd$ because we:

Start with $w$ initial white balls
Have added $k$ white balls in previous steps
Add no new white balls (instead, $d$ black balls are added)
The denominator is still $w+b+nd$ for total balls


You state that "$k$ is the number of white balls added in previous steps".  What exactly do you mean?  Your formulas would make sense if $k$ is the number of times a white ball was drawn from the urn during the first $n-1$ draws, that is what I define as $Y_{n-1}$.

"The numerator becomes w+(k+1)d
because..." I already don't follow what that numerator means and why $X_n$ is a fraction. You have to explain it at a simpler level. What does $X_n$ represent? Also, it may help to describe $b,d,k,n,w$ in a list at the start instead of each individually inside the text.

Is $X_n$ a dummy variable with value $1$ or $0$ depending on whether a white or a black ball has been drawn in the $n$-th step? Or is $X_n$ the fraction of white balls in the urn in the $n$-th step?

You are on the right track, but there are a couple of subtle points that need to be addressed to make the derivation work. The key is to express $X_{n-1}$ in terms of $w$, $k$, $d$, $n$, and $b$ and then carefully take the expectation.
Let's go back to your expression for $E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}]$:
$$ E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}\frac{w^2 + 2w(k+1)d + ((k+1)d)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + (1-X_{n-1})\frac{w^2 + 2wkd + (kd)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} $$
First, let's simplify the expression inside the parentheses. Notice that $w + kd$ is the number of white balls at step $n-1$, which is $(w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1}$. So we can write $k = \frac{(w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1} - w}{d}$. Substituting this into the expression for $E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}]$:
$$ E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] = X_{n-1}\frac{w^2 + 2w((w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1} - w + d) + ((w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1} - w + d)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + (1-X_{n-1})\frac{w^2 + 2w((w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1} - w) + ((w+b+(n-1)d)X_{n-1} - w)^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} $$
Now, let's expand and simplify. After some algebraic manipulation (which is tedious but straightforward), and using the fact that $X_{n-1} = \frac{w+kd}{w+b+(n-1)d}$, we can rewrite the equation as:
$$E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}] = \frac{X_{n-1}^2 d^2 + 2X_{n-1}^2(n-1)d^2 + X_{n-1}^2(n-1)^2d^2 + 2X_{n-1}wd + d^2X_{n-1} + w^2 + 2wd(n-1)X_{n-1}}{(w+b+nd)^2}$$
$$= X_{n-1}^2 \frac{d^2(1 + (n-1))^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + X_{n-1} \frac{2wd + d^2 + 2wd(n-1)}{(w+b+nd)^2} + \frac{w^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$$
$$= X_{n-1}^2 \frac{n^2d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + X_{n-1} \frac{2wdn + d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + \frac{w^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$$
Now we take the expectation of $E[X_n^2|X_{n-1}]$ to get $E[X_n^2]$:
$$E[X_n^2] = E[X_{n-1}^2] \frac{n^2d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + E[X_{n-1}] \frac{2wdn + d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2} + \frac{w^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$$
We know that $E[X_{n-1}] = \frac{w}{w+b}$. Let $A_n = \frac{n^2d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$, $B_n = \frac{2wdn + d^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$, and $C_n = \frac{w^2}{(w+b+nd)^2}$. Then we have a recursive formula:
$$E[X_n^2] = A_n E[X_{n-1}^2] + B_n E[X_{n-1}] + C_n$$
This is a linear recurrence relation. Solving it directly is quite involved. However, we can use the given expression for $\operatorname{Var}(X_n)$ to find $E[X_n^2]$ and verify if it satisfies the recurrence.
Given that $\operatorname{Var}(X_n) = E[X_n](1-E[X_n]) \left(\frac{d}{w+b+d} - \frac{w+b}{w+b+d}\frac{1}{n}\right)$ and $E[X_n] = \frac{w}{w+b}$, we can find $E[X_n^2]$:
$$E[X_n^2] = \operatorname{Var}(X_n) + (E[X_n])^2 = \frac{w}{w+b}\left(1-\frac{w}{w+b}\right) \left(\frac{d}{w+b+d} - \frac{w+b}{w+b+d}\frac{1}{n}\right) + \left(\frac{w}{w+b}\right)^2$$
$$E[X_n^2] = \frac{wb}{(w+b)^2} \left(\frac{nd - (w+b)}{n(w+b+d)}\right) + \frac{w^2}{(w+b)^2}$$
$$E[X_n^2] = \frac{w}{w+b} \left( \frac{w}{w+b} + \frac{b}{w+b} \frac{nd - (w+b)}{n(w+b+d)} \right)$$
Now, you would need to substitute this expression for $E[X_n^2]$ and $E[X_{n-1}^2]$ (replace $n$ with $n-1$) into the recurrence relation and verify that it holds. This will involve some more algebraic manipulation, but it should confirm that the given expression for the variance is correct.

Thank you Willy Wallace for all your hard work! Are there some references on how I can solve this recurrence relation? Ideally, I would have liked to see how to directly solve the recurrence instead of assuming the initial solution is correct and then verifying it.

Let the random variables $I_j$, $j=1,2,\dots,n$, indicate whether we draw a white ball in the $j$th draw.  The key to easily solving the problem is to note that $I_1,I_2,\dots,I_n$ are exchangeable random variables, see the wikipedia page on the Pólya Urn model for a proof.  Thus, these variables all have the same mean and variance and all covariances between them are identical.
Since each $I_j \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(\frac w{w+b})$, we have
$$
E(I_j)=E(I_j^2)=\frac w{w+b}
$$
and
$$
\operatorname{Var}I_j=\frac{wb}{(w+b)^2}.
$$
By considering the two first draws we also have
\begin{align}
E(I_1I_2)&=EE(I_1I_2|I_1) && \text{Law of total expectation}
\\&=E(I_1E(I_2|I_1)) && \text{Pulling out what's known}
\\&=E(I_1 \frac{w+dI_1}{w+b+d})
\\&=\frac1{w+b+d}(wE(I_1) + dE(I_1^2)
\\&=\frac{w(w+d)}{(w+b+d)(w+b)}
\end{align}
and so we find, after some algebra, that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(I_i,I_j)=E(I_iI_j)-E(I_i)E(I_j)=\frac d{w+b+d}\operatorname{Var} I_i.
\end{align}
Defining $Y_n=\sum_{j=1}^n I_j$,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}Y_n&=\frac{wb}{(w+b)^2}\Big(n+n(n-1)\frac d{w+b+d}\Big)
\\&=\frac{nwb(w+b+nd)}{(w+b)^2(w+b+d)}
\end{align}
which agrees with the variance of the equivalent Beta-binomial distribution.
If $X_n$, as suggested in the comments, is taken to be the number of white ball in the urn after replacing the $n$th draw with $d+1$ balls of the same kind, so that
$$
X_n=\frac{w + d Y_n}{w + b + n d},
$$
we obtain
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}X_n&=\frac{nd^2wb}{(w+b)^2(w+b+d)(w+b+nd)}
\end{align}
which admittedly disagrees with your expression suggesting an error.

Thank you Jarle! Can you please show a bit more steps for the "after some algebra" part?

No, after substituting in the expressions for $E(I_iI_j)$ and $E(I_i)$ you just need to put everything on the common denominator $(w+b+d)(w+b)^2$ and the simplify the numerator.  You will then notice that $\operatorname{Var}I_i$ is a factor in the resulting expression.
